# Misunderstanding regarding the Axiom of Union: "All of the elements of some elements of"

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From wikipedia (and translating Halmos' description into first-order logic),

$$ \forall A \exists B \ \forall c (c \in B \iff \exists D(c\in D \ \land \ D \in A )) $$

The usage of $\exists D$ only means that B has all the elements of **at least one** of the elements of A.

So, for example, the [proof of the uniqueness of the unions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Mathematical_Proof_and_the_Principles_of_Mathematics/Sets/Union_and_intersection) of $ A = \{ \{1,2,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$ should not always work.

By the axiom, $\exists U_1 = \{1,2,3\}$ where $D$ is $\{1,2,3\}$ in this case. And $\exists U_2 = \{1,2,3, 4\}$ where $D$ is either $\{1,2,3\} \ \text{or} \ \{2, 4\} $ in this case. Thus, both containing all the elements of "some" elements of $A$, but not being equal.

How would we work around this to ensure that we are taking all the elements of every element of A, or am I just misunderstanding the axiom or the usage of this axiom?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the $\exists D$ quantifier only applies to the second half of the biconditional, not to the biconditional as a whole.  This means that the reverse implication must hold for *every* possible value of $D$ that might make the existential statement true.  In other words, whenever there exists *any* $D$ such that $c\in D$ and $D\in A$, then $c$ must be in $B$.  This forces $B$ to contain the elements of *all* the elements of $A$.

Explicitly, if $A = \{ \{1,2,3\}, \{2,4\}\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$, then $c \in B \iff \exists D(c\in D \ \land \ D \in A )$ is not true for $c=4$, since $c\not\in B$ but there does exist some $D$ such that $c\in D$ and $D\in A$ (namely $D=\{2,4\}$).